# How can I add the build version to a scons build

Tags: scons

At the moment I'm using some magic to get the current git revision into my scons builds.. I just grab the version a stick it into CPPDEFINES.
It works quite nicely ... until the version changes and scons wants to rebuild everything, rather than just the files that have changed - becasue the define that all files use has changed.

Ideally I'd generate a file using a custom builder called `git_version.cpp` and
just have a function in there that returns the right tag. That way only that one file would be rebuilt.

Now I'm sure I've seen a tutorial showing exactly how to do this .. but I can't seem to track it down. And I find the custom builder stuff a little odd in scons...

So any pointers would be appreciated...

Anyway just for reference this is what I'm currently doing:

```
# Lets get the version from git
# first get the base version
git_sha = subprocess.Popen(["git","rev-parse","--short=10","HEAD"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0].strip()
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["git", "status"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "Changed but not updated\\|Changes to be committed"], stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p2.communicate()[0].strip()

if result!="":
  git_sha += "[MOD]"

print "Building version %s"%git_sha

env = Environment()
env.Append( CPPDEFINES={'GITSHAMOD':'"\\"%s\\""'%git_sha} )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a custom Builder since this is just one file. You can use a function (attached to the target version file as an Action) to generate your version file. In the example code below, I've already computed the version and put it into an environment variable. You could do the same, or you could put your code that makes git calls in the `version_action` function.

```
version_build_template="""/*
* This file is automatically generated by the build process
* DO NOT EDIT!
*/

const char VERSION_STRING[] = "%s";

const char* getVersionString() { return VERSION_STRING; }
"""

def version_action(target, source, env):
    """
    Generate the version file with the current version in it
    """
    contents = version_build_template % (env['VERSION'].toString())
    fd = open(target[0].path, 'w')
    fd.write(contents)
    fd.close()
    return 0

build_version = env.Command('version.build.cpp', [], Action(version_action))
env.AlwaysBuild(build_version)
```